# Insert HTML from CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to insert an HTML element, dom or code from CSS(3)?

Comment: No, you cannot insert HTML code from CSS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Content (for text and not html):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html

But just to be clear, it is bad practice. Its support throughout browsers is shaky, and it's generally not a good idea. But in cases where you really have to use it, there it is.

Comment: why is that? I use :after to make elements height dynamic.

Comment: Why its bad? For example i have nice, backgrounded h2 and I must to do like:
`code`(<h1 style="padding-top:10px;">

<img src="images/h1_left.png" class="left"/>
<div class="bg"><div class="text">Dodaj <em style="">ofertę</em></div></div>
<img src="images/h1_right.png" class="right"/>

</h1>)

Comment: Generally, you'd want to use Javascript to achieve this kind of thing. Using `getElementById` with `.innerHTML` and `.value` makes it really easy.

Comment: `<h1 style="padding-top:10px;"> <img src="images/h1_left.png" class="left"/> <div class="bg"><div class="text">Dodaj <em style="">ofertę</em></div></div> <img src="images/h1_right.png" class="right"/> </h1>`

Comment: I don't understand why it's bad practice. Can you elaborate? Is it just a browser support issue? As I understand it, all modern browsers support the property.

Comment: @LwguRi well firstly, yes, browser support. IE before IE8 does not support this property, and Opera 9 supports it in a different way from Firefox and Chrome. Secondly, as I mentioned earlier, this is the kind of thing Javascript is intended to do. It's like using a `<font>` tag. You technically CAN and it will work in Transitional, but you don't use it because that's what CSS is for. You can eat soup with a fork too, but that doesn't mean it's a great idea.

Comment: @MT - I disagree; if I need a colon (`:`) between a `<label>` and its `<input>` that's presentational. Technically that's what CSS is for, but given the above points I suppose a case can be made for using JavaScript instead. But if you mean that specifically @methyl's example is better suited for JS I don't think I have an argument there.

Comment: This is not a correct answer. The correct one is below. You cannot add html with css.

Comment: I have a good use case for this. I am using JavaScript to search the content of elements on the page (hiding unmatched items). So that the search does not return titles that occur on every element, I've put the titles in the css:before. If the term appears in the text of the element it is still returned.

Answer (score 39):

No. The only you can do is to add content (and not an element) using `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element.

More information: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content

Answer (score 14):

No you cannot. The only thing you can do is to insert content. Like so:

```
p:after {
    content: "yo";
}
```

Comment: ::after is a pseudo-element not a pseudo-class

Answer (score 3):

An alternative - which may work for you depending on what you're trying to do - is to have the HTML in place and then use the CSS to show or hide it depending on the class of a parent element.

OR

Use jQuery append()

Answer (score 2):

This can be done. For example with Firefox

CSS

```css
#hlinks {
  -moz-binding: url(stackexchange.xml#hlinks);
}
```

stackexchange.xml

```
<bindings xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <binding id="hlinks">
    <content>
      <children/>
      <html:a href="/privileges">privileges</html:a>
      <html:span class="lsep"> | </html:span>
      <html:a href="/users/logout">log out</html:a>
    </content>
  </binding>
</bindings>
```

[`ref 1`](/a/482088)

[`ref 2`](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/tree/bddd0ff/mozilla/firefox/chrome)