# Use CSS to insert HTML before the content of a selector

Tags: html, css

I have output that is returned via AJAX in the following format (with `#the-poll-options` being the container that the AJAX is inserted in to).

```
<div id="the-poll-options">
    <div class="error-output">
        <p>Blah, blah, bla, etc, etc.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to insert a heading to indicate an error -

```
<div id="the-poll-options">
    <div class="error-output">
        <h3>An error has occurred</h3>
        <p>Blah, blah, bla, etc, etc.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To do this, I've used the following CSS. This works to a point, but actually outputs `<h3>An error has occurred</h3>`, rather than interpreting it as HTML.

```
#the-poll-options .error-output:before{
    content: '<h3>An error has occured</h3>';
}
```

Is it possible to do this with pure CSS, without the need to use JS? Note that I cannot alter the HTML that is returned by the AJAX call. Thanks.

Comment: You can't add HTML using pseudo-elements...so that won't work.

Comment: generated content doesn't build new HTML elements, but you could style it to make it look identical to an `h3` element.

Comment: Imagine replacing your `<h3>` with `<h3 class="error-output">` and the consequences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a `h3` there but you can *format it* like it was `h3`. You have to repeat all formatting rules, though.

```
#the-poll-options .error-output:before{
    content: 'An error has occured';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
    ...
}
```

The style definition within this `:before` class will apply to the *added* content.

Comment: Good idea, hadn't thought of it that way. Thanks.

Comment: I've gone down this route with success. The only thing that didn't work initially was either `margin-` or `padding-bottom`, but adding `display: block;` fixed that.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidGard, I was thinking on mentioning the `display:block`. Actually this `content` is created like a `span` (meaning `inline`d into the content), but `h3` is a `block` element. That's why you have to override that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using JS to do the Ajax call anyway, why not create that h3 inside the Ajax success function?

Comment: I think that is the way I need to go, although I like to stick with HTML/CSS where ever I can, as I feel it's easier to edit in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Plus, ideally no error would occur and the need for inserting the `<h3>` tag wouldn't exist, so it seems unnecessary to have to check every reply to see if it is an error. You still get a +1 though!

Comment: Check every reply?  You are already doing that to some extent...  I assume you're only adding `<div class="error-output">` if an error occurs.  Do it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. With `content` you can only add text. Here is a similar question that you might find helpful: **[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879719/insert-html-from-css)**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can't add HTML using pseudo-elements

You could try this though

**HTML**

```
<div id="the-poll-options">
    <div class="error-output">
        <h3></h3>
        <p>Blah, blah, bla, etc, etc.</p>
    </div>
</div
```

>

**CSS**

```
#the-poll-options .error-output h3:before{
    content: 'An error has occured';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change how the AJAX generate content is returned. Thanks.