# Having a link right after inline list with a fixed HTML structure

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hie everyone,

I have this HTML structure I can't change :

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#">more</a>
</div>
```

The idea is to have the link right after the last "li" without using javascript.

Here is what i want to do :

[image: inline blocks]

And here is [the starter kit with Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BorpF).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879719/insert-html-from-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It working ok

```
  <!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head>

<style>
ul li
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:40px;
    background-color:#FFC0CB;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    height:40px;
}
a
{
        float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#800080;
    height:40px;
    color:white;
    width:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
div ul
{
    width:120px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#">more</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: exactly.. where do you change last element color?

Comment: I'm so stupid i forgot to put li to "float" and not ul. It's a shame, sorry for wasting your time :/ Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css attribute **:last-child** to change style of the last square.

By the way, pay attention to the [compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293369/using-last-child-in-css).

Here a simply [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/MZW9d/4/).

```
ul li {
    background-color: red;
}

ul li:last-child {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Your [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IvAGF) updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <a href="#">more</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

just remove the < L I > and the < / L I > before the < a >