# Css - adding text between

Tags: html, css

I have HTML document, which i am not allowed to changing.
In the other side, i have .css file with which i must to add text. I used the **content** property. The result must have text "NAME" before "input type="text" and text "NUMBER" before "input type="number".

The first one I already did with css code below in the link.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div> 
        <input type="text" />
    </div> 
    <div>
        <input type="number" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My html code is here: http://www.beetxt.com/MZ2/ when I write here in the site it does show nothing.

And my CSS file: http://www.beetxt.com/Tdb/

But I dont know how to show text before " " without changing the HTML file. I can only use .css file, styles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert HTML from CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879719/insert-html-from-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that we have no classes or ID to hook on to we must use `nth-child` statements:

```css
div:nth-child(2) div:first-child::before {
  content: 'NAME';
  display: block;
}
div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: 'NUMBER';
  display: block;
}
.spacer:after {
  content: "SPACER";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one is working fine for me, just one little request more. How to do, that is the words "name" and "number" does not show in the same line that is input ?

Comment: I'm really sorry about my english, it is my third language.
http://s9.postimg.org/s0nc6kp7j/pic1.png
When i use your code i get version 1 on the picture, but i will need version 2 on the picture. Picture is in te link below: http://s9.postimg.org/s0nc6kp7j/pic1.png