# How to add text on image when hovered using only css not html

Tags: css, hover

Am trying to add the text on image when hovered using only css. But through out the internet am finding insertion through html and css

Comment: What is your `HTML` code?

Comment: am keeping only image tag as <img src="anyimage.jpg"> because I want to add text also through css only. So am unable to find it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

Have you searched stack overflow thoroughly?

On my first search i found this:
[Text on image mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149360/text-on-image-mouseover)

I am assuming this is what you want since you have not made your question clear!

Edit: Thanks to tiny more clarification is this what you want to do:
[Using only CSS, show div on hover over <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-a)

Further Edit:

So what you will do is change div to your id for your p. And change your a to img.

Comment: I want to add that p tag on mouse hover only through css

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-a have a look at this

Comment: I want to add that <div> only through css like inserting text on image using only css

Comment: Ok yes it is possible but it is really really bad practice and some browsers will not support it have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879719/insert-html-from-css