# Repeating/Cloning DOM elements with HTML and CSS only

Tags: html, css, dom

Given an HTML template with the following structure:

```
<div id="user-a">
    <span class="entry-1"></span>
    <span class="entry-2"></span>
    <span class="entry-3"></span>
    <span class="entry-4"></span>
    <span class="entry-5"></span>
    <span class="entry-6"></span>
</div>
<div id="user-b">
    <span class="entry-1"></span>
    <span class="entry-2"></span>
    <span class="entry-3"></span>
    <span class="entry-4"></span>
    <span class="entry-5"></span>
    <span class="entry-6"></span>
</div>
<div id="user-c">
    <span class="entry-1"></span>
    <span class="entry-2"></span>
    <span class="entry-3"></span>
    <span class="entry-4"></span>
    <span class="entry-5"></span>
    <span class="entry-6"></span>
</div>
```

etc, is there any way to generate the child < span > elements in HTML without manually adding them for each user?  I will not have access to Javascript or PHP in this environment, only a basic HTML form and an inline style sheet.

Comment: What data needs to be in the elements? And how do you get that data in there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert HTML from CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879719/insert-html-from-css)

Comment: @NicoShultz the elements can be empty. Right now the user data (really just the ID) is added manually.

Comment: @Michel Inserting content with a psuedo-element is something I've attempted, but I'm not sure how I'd include all of the entries within a single :after element. There doesn't seem to be a working :after(n) implementation currently.

Comment: The bottom line of the answer I linked to is: you can't.